# Python http server: handle POST application/octet-stream

Tags: python, http

I have a very basic webserver working with BaseHTTPServer. I can handle simple GET and POST requests (even multipart/form-data), but I am having trouble handling "application/octet-stream". Any hints?

Comment: Please be more specific so that we can help you. What trouble are you having (error messages, exceptions)? Can we see a code sample?

Comment: Thanks for your response, Spike. I don't have a code sample; I'm working with [this example](http://fragments.turtlemeat.com/pythonwebserver.php), but rather than handle multipart/form-data I would like to grab the contents of an otet-stream.

Comment: You still didn't tell us what you are seeing as spike requested.

Answer (score 2):

The `cgi` module's form parser is meant only for `multipart/form-data`.

Single part forms - meaning anything with a standard MIME type in `self.headers.getheader('content-type')` - are available to you as the normal binary data via `self.rfile` - no need to parse them.

Take a look here:

- http://docs.python.org/library/basehttpserver.html
- http://docs.python.org/library/cgi.html
- http://fragments.turtlemeat.com/pythonwebserver.php

Furthermore, don't be confused by that cgi stuff. It appears to be antiquated naming convention from the old days (pre Ruby-on-Rails) when cgi was common and web frameworks were unheard of.